# Number of intersections dependent on order of intersecting data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I try to compute the number of intersections of two data frames but the results differ depending on whether I intersect A with B or B with A. How can that be?

```
a_b= a.index.intersection(b.index)
b_a= b.index.intersection(a.index)
len(a_b), len(b_a)
```

returns

```
(10735, 10927)
```

Unfortunately the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) isn't quite helpful on this one.

Comment: This returns ```'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'intersection'```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Index are often supposed to only contain unique values, and weird things happen when this *requirement* is not met. I assume that you are experiencing it. Here is a short example exhibiting the problem:

```
>>> dfa = pd.DataFrame(1, index=list('ABCDAC'), columns=['X'])
>>> dfa
>>> dfb = pd.DataFrame(1, index=list('ABCEC'), columns=['X'])
>>> dfa.index.intersection(dfb.index)
Index(['A', 'B', 'C', 'C'], dtype='object')
>>> dfb.index.intersection(dfa.index)
Index(['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C'], dtype='object')
>>>
```

Behaviour with non unique indexes is not explicit in the documentation, and I would not rely on it without that.

So my advice (if it is relevant in your use case) is to use `unique()` on both indexes:

```
a_b= a.index.unique().intersection(b.index.unique())
b_a= b.index.unique().intersection(a.index.unique())
len(a_b), len(b_a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though the intersection of both indices will contain the same elements in both cases, the intersection *can* contain duplicate elements (unlike what would happen when using `set.difference`). Note that indices allow for *set-like* operations, however the behavior can be different, as in the cases where indices are duplicated.

So the difference in lengths accounts for the fact that both indices contain different amount of duplicates. Here's an example thgat illustrates this:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(index=np.random.randint(0,10, 10))
b = pd.DataFrame(index=np.random.randint(0,10, 10))

int_1 = a.index.intersection(b.index)
int_2 = b.index.intersection(a.index)

len(int_1)
# 7

len(int_2)
# 5
```

Even though the `Index.difference` is empty:

```
int_1.difference(int_2)
# Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
```

As mentioned the difference in length accounts for the fact the the amount of duplicates in both indices is different:

```
int_1.duplicated().sum()
# 3

int_2.duplicated().sum()
# 1
```